# Объяснение пунктуации в сложносочинённом предложении

Tags: запятые, ссп

Каким правилом можно объяснить пунктуацию в следующем предложении?

*Либо мы идём на горки и я покупаю тебе мороженое, либо ты сидишь дома и ничего не делаешь.*

С одной стороны, первая часть сложного предложения кажется неделимым целым, между которым интуитивно запятая не ставится, с другой — сложно найти правило, в котором чётко сказано, что в таких случаях знак перед "и" не нужен.

Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю, что запятую надо поставить:

*Либо **мы идём на гОрки, и я покупаю тебе мороженое,** либо ты сидишь дома и ничего не делаешь.*

**Пояснение**

1. Это предложение можно рассматривать **как сложное синтаксическое целое**, а в этом случае учитываем следующее: http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=136#pp136

§ 132. В сложных синтаксических конструкциях, распадающихся на крупные логико-синтаксические блоки, которые сами по себе являются **сложными предложениями** или в которых один из блоков оказывается сложным предложением, на стыке блоков ставятся знаки препинания, указывающие на взаимоотношения блоков, **при сохранении внутренних знаков, поставленных на своем собственном синтаксическом основании.**

2. Рассмотрим отдельно ССП: ***Мы идём на горки, и я покупаю тебе мороженое.*** Здесь нет общих элементов (сочинительный союз ЛИБО  таким элементом быть не может). Поэтому запятая ставится.
3. **Интонационно** здесь возможно произношение как с паузой, так и без паузы, во втором случае запятая будет **грамматической.**
4. Пример:

Либо она именно вчера по каким-то причинам должна была встать очень рано, либо **ты прав, и она ложилась днем отдыхать**, поставив будильник на половину шестого. [Александра Маринина. Светлый лик смерти (1996)]

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, что запятую ставить не нужно.

У Розенталя имеется запрет лишь на противительные союзы. Это как бы намекает на то, что у других союзов есть потенциал для объединения. Не будь это так, Розенталь запретил бы все союзы, а не лишь один тип. *Либо* — это разделительный союз.
http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133
Не стал бы делать ударение на слове "горки" и паузу.

Здесь явно ощущается объединение:
*Либо {мы идём на горки и я покупаю тебе морОженое}, либо ты сидишь дома и ничего не дЕлаешь.*
Дополнительная запятая разбивает первую ситуацию. А нам нужно показать, что их две, а не три.

Answer (score 1):

**Комментарий к ответу oleedd**

1. **Ощущение** — это не обоснование.  В примере из Нацкорпуса с распространенным предложением тоже не будете ставить запятую, там у вас какое ощущение?  И везде **самодеятельность и индивидуальные решения**,  а здесь нужны **стандартные грамматические модели.**
2. Вы не понимаете смысла **общего элемента** – это должно быть **знаменательное, а не служебное слово**.

Союзы (не союзные аналоги) как раз используются для построения **грамматических моделей**, а в ПАС указано, что внутренние конструкции  в сложном синтаксическом целом оформляются **по своим правилам**.

3. **У вас есть ссылка** на подобные конструкции  или примеры из Нацкорпуса, которые иначе описывали бы данную ситуацию?  Например, союз ЛИБО как общий элемент. И не надо изучать грамматику по Розенталю (это справочник по правописанию).
4. **Интонация дополняет грамматику**, а вы ее ставите на передовую позицию. Это неверно и дискредитирует сам принцип.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138732/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon-----).

Comment: Да всё я хочу. Какое значение не заметил? Не надо таких образных, художественных обвинений, они беспочвенны.

Comment: oleedd, у меня времени не очень много, а ведь я вам все уже рассказала о том, какие глаголы можно использовать, если предмет находится вдалеке, а мы его слышим или видим. И на форуме вам говорили то же самое, примеры из словаря приводили.  Но убедить вас все равно не могли.  Что ж повторяться.  Вот о стихах я бы поговорила, да не знаю где. Есть ли такие форумы?